# Telerik Creating a StackedBarChart

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm Fairly new to WPF and MVVM in general, I'm trying to follow this tutorial to create a stacked bar chart in telerik/WPF C#:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/knowledge-base/chartview-summary-labels-stacked-bars
But I'm, unsure where to implement the "Custom Renderer and Labels" Code, Can't seem to have it work. Should I declare a seperate class or something? A rough step by step guide is all i need, thanks in advance

this is the example code (I'm not sure where to put it)

```
public class CustomCartesianRenderer : CartesianRenderer
{
    public CustomCartesianRenderer(CartesianArea area)
        : base(area)
    { }

    protected override void InitializeSeriesLabels()
    {
        base.InitializeSeriesLabels();

        IDictionary<object, List<double?>> summaryValues = new Dictionary<object, List<double?>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Area.Series.Count; i++)
        {
            BarSeries barSeries = this.Area.Series[i] as BarSeries;
            if (barSeries == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < barSeries.DataPoints.Count; j++)
            {
                CategoricalDataPoint dp = (CategoricalDataPoint)barSeries.DataPoints[j];
                if (!summaryValues.ContainsKey(dp.Category))
                {
                    summaryValues.Add(dp.Category, new List<double?>() { dp.Value });
                }
                else
                {
                    summaryValues[dp.Category].Add(dp.Value);
                }
            }
        }

        string lastSeriesName = this.Area.Series[this.Area.Series.Count - 1].Name;
        for (int i = 0; i < this.DrawParts.Count; i++)
        {
            BarLabelElementDrawPart labelPart = this.DrawParts[i] as BarLabelElementDrawPart;
            if (labelPart != null && labelPart.Element.Name == lastSeriesName)
            {
                CustomBarLabelElementDrawPart customLabelPart = new CustomBarLabelElementDrawPart((BarSeries)labelPart.Element, this);
                customLabelPart.SummaryValues = summaryValues;
                this.DrawParts[i] = customLabelPart;
            }
        }
    }
}
public class CustomBarLabelElementDrawPart : BarLabelElementDrawPart
{
    private IDictionary<object, List<double?>> summaryValues;

    public CustomBarLabelElementDrawPart(BarSeries series, IChartRenderer renderer)
        : base(series, renderer)
    { }

    public IDictionary<object, List<double?>> SummaryValues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.summaryValues;
        }
        set
        {
            this.summaryValues = value;
        }
    }

    public override void Draw()
    {
        Graphics graphics = this.Renderer.Surface as Graphics;
        RadGdiGraphics radGraphics = new RadGdiGraphics(graphics);

        foreach (DataPointElement dataPointElement in this.Element.Children)
        {
            CategoricalDataPoint categoricalDataPoint = dataPointElement.DataPoint as CategoricalDataPoint;
            if (!this.summaryValues.ContainsKey(categoricalDataPoint.Category))
            {
                continue;
            }

            double? sum = this.summaryValues[categoricalDataPoint.Category].Sum();
            string summaryText = string.Format("Sum: {0}", sum);

            RadRect slot = categoricalDataPoint.LayoutSlot;
            RectangleF barBounds = new RectangleF((float)(this.OffsetX + slot.X), (float)(this.OffsetY + slot.Y), (float)slot.Width, (float)slot.Height);
            float realHeight = barBounds.Height * dataPointElement.HeightAspectRatio;
            barBounds.Y += barBounds.Height - realHeight;
            barBounds.Height = realHeight;
            barBounds = this.AdjustBarDataPointBounds(dataPointElement, barBounds);
            barBounds.Width = Math.Max(barBounds.Width, 1f);

            object state = radGraphics.SaveState();

            int horizontalTranslate = (int)(barBounds.X + barBounds.Width / 2);
            int verticalTranslate = (int)(barBounds.Y + barBounds.Height / 2);

            float angle = (float)this.Element.LabelRotationAngle % 360f;

            if (angle != 0)
            {
                radGraphics.TranslateTransform(horizontalTranslate, verticalTranslate);
                radGraphics.RotateTransform(angle);
                radGraphics.TranslateTransform(-horizontalTranslate, -verticalTranslate);
            }

            Size desiredSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(summaryText, dataPointElement.Font);

            FillPrimitiveImpl fill = new FillPrimitiveImpl(dataPointElement, null);
            fill.PaintFill(radGraphics, 0, Size.Empty, barBounds);

            BorderPrimitiveImpl border = new BorderPrimitiveImpl(dataPointElement, null);
            border.PaintBorder(radGraphics, 0, Size.Empty, barBounds);

            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(dataPointElement.ForeColor))
            {
                RectangleF drawRectangle = new RectangleF();
                drawRectangle.X = barBounds.X + dataPointElement.Padding.Left + (barBounds.Width - desiredSize.Width) /2;
                drawRectangle.Y = barBounds.Y + dataPointElement.Padding.Top - desiredSize.Height;
                drawRectangle.Width = barBounds.Width - dataPointElement.Padding.Right;
                drawRectangle.Height = barBounds.Height - dataPointElement.Padding.Bottom;

                StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
                graphics.DrawString(summaryText, dataPointElement.Font, brush, drawRectangle, format);
            }

            if (angle != 0)
            {
                radGraphics.ResetTransform();
            }

            radGraphics.RestoreState(state);

        }

        base.Draw();
    }

    private RectangleF AdjustBarDataPointBounds(DataPointElement point, RectangleF bounds)
    {
        RectangleF barBounds = bounds;

        if (point.BorderBoxStyle == BorderBoxStyle.SingleBorder || point.BorderBoxStyle == BorderBoxStyle.OuterInnerBorders)
        {
            barBounds.X += point.BorderWidth - (int)((point.BorderWidth - 1f) / 2f);
            barBounds.Width -= point.BorderWidth;
            barBounds.Y += point.BorderWidth - (int)((point.BorderWidth - 1f) / 2f);
            barBounds.Height -= point.BorderWidth;
        }
        else if (point.BorderBoxStyle == BorderBoxStyle.FourBorders)
        {
            barBounds.Y += 1;
            barBounds.Height -= 1;
            barBounds.X += 1;
            barBounds.Width -= 1;
        }

        if (((CartesianRenderer)this.Renderer).Area.Orientation == System.Windows.Forms.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            barBounds.X--;
        }

        return barBounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: **WPF != WinForms**

Comment: OH GOD YOURE RIGHT! Is there anyway I can somehow port it into my WPF project